# System.Runtime.Caching doesn't release BitmapImage objects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caching, .net-4.0

I'm using the new System.Runtime.Caching library for caching in my application, and defined it as follows in the App.config:

```
<system.runtime.caching>
    <memoryCache>
        <namedCaches>
            <add name="MyCache" cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes="10"
                 physicalMemoryLimitPercentage="30" pollingInterval="00:00:10" />
        </namedCaches>
    </memoryCache>
</system.runtime.caching>
```

Then, from code I instantiate it like this: `_cache = new MemoryCache("MyCache");`

And add entries like this: `_cache.Add(resourceName, resource, new CacheItemPolicy());`

I use this cache to store `BitmapImage` objects, and to make sure the cache works properly, I've added ten `BitmapImage` objects to the cache, each holding an image of about 7MB. I then waited ten seconds for the polling to occur and checked the entries in the cache, but they were all there. Not a single object has been evicted.

Am I doing something wrong here? I know the settings are read from the App.config correctly. Is it possible that the `BitmapImage` instances themselves are small and only reference the image on the disk? And how does the cache determine what's the object's size?

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are adding to the cache with

```
new CacheItemPolicy()
```

This will override your values and give you the defaults, which is an AbsoluteExpiration of 31/12/9999 11:59:59 PM +00:00

to do it for 10 minutes you have 2 options

```
CacheItemPolicy item = new CacheItemPolicy();

item.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

or

```
item.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
```

If you choose the sliding expiration the 10 minutes will reset if you update the object.

Comment: I've tested this with `char[]`, and items were evicted even though I used `new CacheItemPolicy()`. Either way, in order to add an item to the cache, I have to supply a `CacheItemPolicy` parameter. What value do I need to pass then in order to get the requested behavior?

Comment: This still doesn't give me the requested behavior. I don't want to explicitly set the time when the items will expire - I want them to expire if the memory limit, as defined in `app.config`, was exceeded. Also, I'm pretty sure you're wrong about the items expiring at 31/12/9999 11:59:59 PM +00:00, because as I said in my comment above, I did get items to expire even when I added them with the policy `new CacheItemPolicy()`.